# How create collection remotely form mlab api in remote-mongodb using nodejs,expressjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, express, mlab

I am following [Brad Traversy's](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector) MERN stack development course and In 4th section, I can't make `post` request to route `localhost:5000/api/profile`,

after sending `post request` with data as `handle,status,skills` which are fields in my collection, it returns error `skills field required`.

[image: screenshot]

skills is array of strings sent from user-input.

when I checked `collection-profile` is created or not then it's not created and only one collection is shown as main collection `user`,

[image: screenshot]

I followed each line of code in tutorial but getting error, I wanted to get `Profile collection` to be created at remote mlab mongodb,

my `profile` model code is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  company: {
    type: String
  },
  website: {
    type: String
  },
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  githubusername: {
    type: String
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: String
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profile", ProfileSchema);
```

using `validator.js` module, I am validating input-fields,

```
  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.skills)) {
    errors.skills = "Skills field is required";
  }
```

so, I can't find why exactly I can't find new collection as profile?

I tried using mongodb-locally, but it didn't help.

my Github [repo link](https://github.com/ganeshdeshmukh1612/connect-geeks).

Comment: I manually, created `profile` collection, but error persists, as `skills field is necessory` even though I sent array of values, separeted by comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned user's details when route `/api/users/current` and changed `response on success`

before changing:

```
res.json({ msg: "Success" });
```

after:

```
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {

    res.json({
      id: req.user.id,
      name: req.user.name,
      email: req.user.email
    });
  }
);
```

Here is my commit history,

[image: my comment]

then It didn't give error as `skills field is required`,

[image]